# Combine two expression together?

Tags: c#, expression

I'm building an application to translate string to lambda expression. For example, if the input is a string like `"c.id>7 && c.grade<5"` , I should translate it to `c=>c.id>7 && c.grade<5`; if the input is string like `"c.id>7 && u.grade<5"` ,I should translate it to `(c,u)=>c.id>7 && u.grade<5`.

I'v built an application to recognize the string `"c.id>7 && c.grade<5"` ,and translate it to two expressions `c=>c.id>7` and `c=>c.grade<5`. But when I try to combine the two expressions together like below:

```
// expression1 is c=>c.id>7, expression1 is return by method Expression.Lambda
// expression2 is c=>c.grade<5 or u.grade<5, expression2 is return by method Expression.Lambda
Expression.AndAlso(expression1, expression2);
```

System said

```
there is no binary opertor AndAlso between System.Func`2[Test.user, System.Boolean] and System.Func`2[Test.user, System.Boolean]
```

So who can help me combine the two expressions together, thanks!

ps:

```
// expression1 and expression2 is built like below    
Expression expression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.AndAlso(leftExpression, rightExpression), parameterExpressions.ToArray());
```

Comment: What are the types of `expressions1` and `expressions2`?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen , expression1 and expression2 are built by method Expression.Lambda

Comment: I still want you to show exactly what the types are, please show the declarations of `expressions1` and `expressions2`, if you're using `var`, please get Visual Studio to replace it with the actual type, then show the declarations.

Comment: Hope these items helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/457328/4373895 AND https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613631/4373895

Comment: Maybe try [Combining two `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457328/7571171) ? Also, please add some more information to your question (i.e. what are the types of `leftExpression` and `rightExpression`?). See [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow, the reason I post the question is I think it is not as simple as  combine two Expression<Func<T, bool>>. I don't know which type of lambda expression I need to combine. This time, I need combine  Expression<Func<T1, bool>> with Expression<Func<T1, bool>> to Func<T1, bool>, and next time probably I need combine  Expression<Func<T1, bool>> with Expression<Func<T2, bool>> to Func<T1, T2,bool>. This is totally decide at running time.

Comment: How many input parameters can accept lambda? You provided examples with 1-2 params, but can it accept more? How do you decide what lambda input param is basing on input string? I mean, how do you know what `c` and `u` input params should be?